# is there a way to sync the data entered into a customer feedback system to my site?

Tags: mysql, database, feedback, uservoice, get-satisfaction

Hi I am a neeewwwb at anything programming related so I don't know if this will even make sense.  My question is, is there a way to sync a customer feedback system (like User Voice or Getsatisfaction) to my site or to a database for my site?  So essentially if a user entered info into the User Voice tool, it would simultaneously show up at a different page on my site too.  ty!

Comment: I would say this is going to depend very much on the particular customer feedback system and whether they offer an API to site developers such as yourself.  You should be able to determine this by a quick search of their website.

Answer (score 1):

Both UserVoice and GetSatisfaction have APIs for this.

UserVoice has public API available for all subscription plans (including the one that's free), that should be sufficient to import data.

GetSatisfaction API doesn't require you to have an account and allows anonymous data retrieval (.xml and .json output).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the uservoice api does support some sort of export, though I have no experience with it: http://uservoice.com/faq#api .

My guess is you need a paid account for that.

Comment: UserVoice's Free/Basic account does have access to Public API that should be sufficient to retrieve the data, according to their "Products, plans & pricing" page.